# Prove that if $\Gamma$ is inconsistent, then $\Gamma$ doesn’t have a model.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

The task is to prove that If set of sentences $\Gamma$ is inconsistent, then $\Gamma$ doesn't have a model. It is a corollary of Soundness Theorem: If $\Gamma\vdash A$, then $\Gamma\models A$. Could anyone explain how to prove it?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? What are some things you already know about models and the definition of $\models$? (BTW I've TeXified your question; see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), and if there's a symbol you don't know the LaTeX code for you can usually find it via [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org).)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\Gamma$ is inconsistent, then for some formula $\phi$, $\Gamma\vdash\phi,\neg\phi$. By the soundness theorem, $\Gamma\vDash\phi,\neg\phi$. Any model for $\Gamma$ thus satisfies $\phi$, but then it cannot satisfy $\neg\phi$, which is a contradiction, so $\Gamma$ has no model.

Comment: Yeah, note that the definition of satisfaction means $\mathcal{M} \models \varphi$ iff $\mathcal{M} \not\models \neg\varphi$ and $\mathcal{M} \models \neg\varphi$ iff $\mathcal{M} \not\models \varphi$ when $\varphi$ is a sentence.

Comment: Can you assume the antecedent to be true in trying to show this proof though?